# jQuery : how to apply effect on a child element

Tags: javascript, jquery

instead of re-writing the same function, I want to optimise my code :

```
<div class="header">
    <h3>How to use the widget</h3>
    <span  id="idwidget" ></span>
</div>

<div class="content" id="widget">
```

the JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var showText="Show";
        var hideText="Hide";
        $("#idwidget").before(
            "<a href='#' class='button' id='toggle_link'>"+showText+"</a>"
        );
        $('#widget').hide();
        $('a#toggle_link').click(function() {
            if ($('a#toggle_link').text()==showText) {
                $('a#toggle_link').text(hideText);
            } else {
                $('a#toggle_link').text(showText);
            }
            $('#widget').toggle('slow');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is working just with the div which is called widget and the button called idwidget.

But on this page i have also :

```
<div class="header">
    <h3>How to eat APPLES</h3>
    <span id="IDsomethingelse" ></span>
</div>

<div class="content" id="somethingelse">
```

And I want it to be compatible with the code.

I heard about children attribute, do you have an idea how to do that please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example snippets of HTML, the following should work (it grabs the all `.content` `div`s and works backwards to find the associated `span`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var showText="Show";
        var hideText="Hide";
        $(".content").each(function() {
            var $content = $(this).hide();
            $("<a href='#' class='button' >"+showText+"</a>")
                .insertBefore($("#id" + $content.attr("id")))
                .click(function() {
                    if ($(this).text() == showText) {
                        $(this).text(hideText);
                    } else {
                        $(this).text(showText);
                    }
                    $content.toggle('slow');
                    return false;
                 });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Edit**: I've compacted the code a little (but it now requires jQuery 1.4 for the `.text(function)` bit).

**Edit 2**: Ok still more compact than the original, but back to 1.3.X safe code.

Comment: what you can achieve by doing "$content = $(this).hide();"? does .hide() method also return something?

Comment: @gryzzly - most functions in jQuery return the object you're manipulating so that you can chain things together... So `var $content = $(this).hide();` is the same as `var $content = $(this); $content.hide();`. So just making the code a little more compact.

Comment: Thank you, it's perfect ! ;)    15char

Comment: @alconja in the show/hide button, when clicking on SHOW, instead of showing 'HIDE' it's showing : function(idx,text) {return text == showText:showText; }

Comment: @Tristan - what version of jQuery are you using? I'm guessing its 1.3.X (the `.text(function)` syntax is new to 1.4), since it looks like its setting the text to the literal function... I'll switch it back to 1.3 safe code.

Comment: yes, indeed i'm using 1.3.x in this part of the website. There is no bigdeal, i'm gonna update to 1.4.2. Sry, i forgot i had 2 different version on the website. Thanks again ;)

Comment: @Tristan - No worries. Glad to help. If you (or anyone else who comes looking in the future) wants the 1.4 version, you can [grab it from the revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b947c1d8-fa78-4b8f-854b-e60119b8f44b/view-source).